# Firefox Webdriver is not getting launched from Testsuite while running a selenium maven script via Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have created a Freestyle project in Jenkins and then added the maven related pom file information under Build->Invoke top-level Maven targets.
Now when I create the build, I am seeing that the build is successful, but my objective for creating the build is not being achieved.

### This is the message that I can see:

### T E S T S

Running TestSuite
WebDriver is:FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (175e0877-749c-4f84-a67c-be856c04d741)
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.708 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: please post relevent code - test class, pom file and testng xml

Comment: I am not able to post here these due to the file size. Can you kindly suggest any other alternatives please?

Comment: just edit the question and copy paste the relevant code.

Comment: What command you perform when you run that locally? How is it different from what Jenkins prints in console log?

Comment: You mean the test suite is not launched.
What is the command?
Is there any execution difference between the Jenkins environment and your desktop?
What do you call a "Selenium Maven Script"?